# Locating a input of type email with SafariWatir

Tags: watir, safariwatir

I just started using Watir to write some simple tests for my web application.

First thing I want to do is to populate an login form with an email input element of type "email" with SafariWatir on OS X.

This won't work:

```
browser.text_field(:id, "email").set('my@email.com')
```

Trace:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/safariwatir-0.4.0/lib/safariwatir/scripter.rb:661:in `execute': Unable to locate TextField, using :id and "email" (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/safariwatir-0.4.0/lib/safariwatir/scripter.rb:303:in `focus'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/safariwatir-0.4.0/lib/safariwatir.rb:525:in `set'
    from test.rb:10
```

I assume that the element is not matched because of the different type attribute value. The documentation does not state any specification for this kind of elements. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Update: adding (reformatted) HTML sample based on user's comment that they are testing pinganalytics

```
<form action="http://pingalytics.com/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email</label> 
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" id="email" autofocus=""  /> 
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"  /> 
  </p>
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in with Pingdom" class="primary" />
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.pingdom.com/signup/">
      Sign up
    </a>
    , or 
    <a href="https://pp.pingdom.com/index.php/login" title="Reset your Pingdom password">
      recover your password
    </a>
    .
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: SafariWatir is basically an inactive project. You should consider using [Watir-Webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/safari/) instead.

Comment: I would also advise you to put the html for the page being tested (or a link to the page).

Comment: Testing out http://pingalytics.com I will try out Watir-Webdriver. Thx!

Comment: I added the html since the OP did not take hint provided by @DaveMcNulla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 'email' type for an input element is new as of HTML5.  Safariwatir is an older project which pretty much predates HTML5.  It has not seen a lot of recent work and it is highly unlikely it would be looking for this type when searching for potential 'text_field' elements.

Watir 3.0 or Watir-webdriver would be a safer bet as a lot of work has gone into those to bring them up to properly supporting HTML5.

Also since Webdriver has just recently added support for Safari ([see here for instructions)](http://watirwebdriver.com/safari/), it is now a viable alternative to safariwatir  (which I highly expect will see no further work going forward.) 
The Safari support is still a tiny bit DYI as you have to build your own safari extension and it only works on a Mac, but that may change if we see someone start publishing a standard safari extension that could be downloaded from an online gallery